# Tcl list of available channles

Tags: tcl, channel

Is there a way to get a list of tcl channels available? I am using a third party tool which has built in tcl interpreter so after i do `close stdout`, it still prints the output to the prompt.

Suspecting that it is using another channel because after closing stdout, i tried `puts "hello"` and it gives an error *no channel named stdout found*

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chan names ?pattern?` will return a list of the open channels, optionally matching the pattern.

http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M27

Answer (score 1):

Beware that a channel may be shared by interpreters. Consider the following code:

```
interp create foo
interp share {} stdout foo
close stdout
chan names; # stdin stderr
puts hello; # can not find channel named "stdout"
foo eval {puts hello}; # hello
```

So even if stdout has been closed in one interpreter, it may still be available to other interpreters.

In fact, it is not even necessary to explicitly share stdout with the slave interpreter, unless it was created as a safe interpreter. The standard I/O channels are automatically shared with regular interpreters.

Without more information on the inner workings of the third party tool, it will be difficult to say for sure what is going on.

Comment: Assuming there is another interpreter executing those commands and printing the output to stdout, is there a way to find what interpreters are currently running?

Comment: @almostacoder Interpreters can't see their parents; that's a security feature.

Comment: @DonalFellows, but how do i know that they are child interpreters running in the code? can child interpreters see other child in the same level?

Comment: Unless a parent interpreter has implemented special provisions, interpreters can only see their children and further down, using the `interp slaves` command.

Comment: thanks @SchelteBron, @DonalFellows. I will lookup `interp` for further details

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for a Tcl interpreter to have the `puts` command overridden so that it can write to something that works like stdout even if you do `close stdout`. It's even fairly easy to do (if you're running in a child interpreter and `puts` is aliased to something in the parent). The only reason it is at all fiddly is because the pattern of arguments to `puts` is not a good fit for how procedures map arguments to formal parameters. Here's a version that's wrong — it's missing a lot of parsing code — but close.

```
proc magicPuts {interp args} {
    if {[llength $args] == 1} {
        puts [lindex $args 0]
    } else {
        $interp invokehidden puts {*}$args
    }
}
set subinterp [interp create]
interp hide $subinterp puts
interp alias $subinterp puts {} magicPuts $subinterp
interp share {} stdout $subinterp

$subinterp eval { source yourscript.tcl }
```